# Prevent Drop View in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

How to prevent a user from not dropping a view even he/she has previlige to do so? I have a view being used by an application. However, it was dropped by a user a couple times. Is there something like REVOKE DROP ANY VIEW? Do I have to use a trigger for that?

Comment: "prevent a user from dropping a view  he/she has previlige to do so" Why does he have such privileges in the first place?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov In our scenario, a generic admin account is used by multiple users for admin purpose.

Comment: well... in that case the view is not the only object to worry about

Comment: Agreed with Pavel. Littlefoot gave an example of something that would work well, but honestly, the problem is that a user has the privilege to do something they are not supposed to do. While you may have had a problem with just one view for now, chances are that you will have the problem with other objects too. It can be tough working with developers/teams that believe they need root-level access for everything and don't believe in least privilege, however, this will almost assuredly become an ongoing problem if you do not have a conversation about separation of duties and least privilege.

Comment: We haven't had any issues on this since ony 2 are admins in our group and the view was created recently with a suffix of "_test". It was dropped during some database maintenance routine. I totally agree with you guys that we need a more robust solution. but I just wonder if technically there is a way to prevent a view or table to be dropped like this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger might help. Here's an example.

First, a few objects to be dropped:

```
SQL> create table test as select * From emp where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace view v_dept as select * From dept;

View created.

SQL>
```

I don't want to allow V_DEPT to be dropped, so:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_drop
  2    before drop on schema
  3  declare
  4    l_name varchar2(30);
  5  begin
  6    select ora_dict_obj_name
  7      into l_name
  8      from dual;
  9    if l_name = 'V_DEPT' then
 10       raise_application_error(-20001, 'Forbidden');
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> drop view v_dept;
drop view v_dept
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: Forbidden
ORA-06512: at line 8


SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```